# Classification of All Constructible Angles

Tags: reference-request, geometric-construction

I am familiar with the famous Gauss-Wantzel Theorem which states that a polygon is constructible with compass and straightedge if and only its number of sides is a power of two multiplied by a product of distinct Fermat primes. This theorem then provides a list of constructible angles. My question is whether a similar theorem for all constructible angles exists, that is, a necessary and sufficient condition for an angle $\alpha$ to be constructible using only compass and straightedge. Are there other constructible angles (which of course would not be the interior angles of a polygon) which are not of the form implied by the Gauss-Wantzel Theorem,and if so, what do they have in common with one another?

If possible, I would greatly appreciate a link to the theorem and its proof.

Comment: To what common criterion should the set of angles be R&C constructed?

Comment: I don't know this subject (I'm not a professional mathematician), and I don't know if the following reference can be interesting for you, I refer it if you want to read it in your home, this is a very nice reference that I've found few days ago when I was searching on arXiv about articles related to origami (see the Wikipedia Origami),. Thus if I refer well the literature is Jorge C. Lucero, *Division of an angle into equal parts and construction of regular polygons by multi-fold origami*, Forum Geometricorum, 19, pp. 45-52 (2019). The corresponding preprint on arXiv should be **1902.01649**